# Create cumsum column with Python Script Widget in Orange

Tags: python, orange

I can't create one new column with the cumulative sum of another. 
Orange documentation is to hard to understand if you are new to Python like me.

This is the code i have in my Python Script Widget

```
import numpy as np

## make a copy from the data that widget recieves
out_data = in_data.copy()

## compute cumulative sum of column values
newCumsumColValues = np.cumsum(out_data[:,('myCumsumcolTarget')])                

## i got the values
print(newCumsumColValuesl)        

## i need to create a new column with the values in out_data
## i've tried to update column values first to test

## with an static value column values updated to 8
out_data[:,'myCumsumcolTarget'] = 8    

## with newCumsumColValue is NOT working
out_data[:,'myCumsumcolTarget'] = newCumsumColValues
```

These examples are hard to understand for me:

https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/data/pythonscript.html
https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/tutorial/data.html#exploration-of-the-data-domain

Thanks in advance,
Vince.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
out_data.X[:, i] = newCumsumColValues
```

where `i` is

```
out_data.domain.index(out_data.domain['myCumsumcolTarget'])
```

This code is a bit complicated but it works.

Comment: Thank you so much @Matphy, works perfectly. You are right, is a bit complicated. Regards.